# Get WooCommerce order item custom fields values from their meta key

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am trying to make a custom order page where I can display all orders details to the front end.

I have created a product with custom fields. Now i am trying to display the metadata of the order but I want to select certain values from the array.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array('status'=> 'on-hold');
$orders = wc_get_orders($args);

foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $order_items = wc_get_order($order_id);
     //echo $order_items;

    foreach( $order_items->get_items() as  $item ){
        $item_data           = $item->get_data();
        $item_meta_data      = $item->get_meta_data();
        $formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( '_', true );

        //echo '<pre>' . print_r($item_meta_data, true) . '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($formatted_meta_data, true) . '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Here is what I am getting :

```
Array
(
    [45] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => Characters
            [value] => Character1 ($29.00)
Character2 ($29.00)
            [display_key] => Characters
            [display_value] => 

Character1 ($29.00)

Character2 ($29.00)


        )

    [46] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => More
            [value] =>  Card ($40.00)
 Bounties ($15.00)
            [display_key] => More
            [display_value] => 

 Card ($40.00)

 Bounties ($15.00)


        )

)


//etc
```

What I am trying to do is getting something like this:

```
Character1 ($29.00)
Character2 ($29.00)

Card ($40.00)
Bounties ($15.00)
```

Comment: I meant "certain". your answer what I want. thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WC_Date method get_meta() from your desired meya keys as follows:

```
// Get orders
$orders = wc_get_orders( array( 'status'=> 'on-hold', 'limit' => -1 ) );

// Loop through the array of WC_Order Objects
foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    // Get order Id
    $order_id = $order->get_id(); 
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as  $item ) {
        // Get "Characters" item custom field
        $characters = $item->get_meta('Characters');
        if ( $characters ) {
            echo '<p>Characters: ' . $characters . '</p>'; // Display
        }
        
        // Get "More" item custom field
        $more = $item->get_meta('More');
        if ( $more ) {
            echo '<p>More: ' . $more . '</p>'; // Display
        }
    }
}
```

It should work